# Match two df and tag with column name

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

df1

```
    1A 1B 1C
    a1 b1 c1
    a2 b2 c2
    a3 b3 c4
```

df2

```
  ID
  a1
  b1
  c4
  a3
```

I want to tag each row in df2 with df matching column name.

Desired Output

```
ID ID_name
a1  1A
b1  1B
c4  1C
a3  1A
a8  NaN
```

These are my code and it does what i want,

```
save_p = []
for ix,row1 in df2.iterrows():
    for ix2, row2 in df1.iterrows():
        if row1.1A == row2.ID:
            save_p.append((row2.ID,'1A'))
        if row1.1B == row2.ID:
            save_p.append((row2.ID,'1B'))
        if row1.1C == row2.ID:
            save_p.append((row2.ID,'1C'))
```

........etc
but i want some best/eligant way to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), also if no match get missing value(s) like `c3`, because no in `df1`:

```
s = df1.melt().set_index('value')['variable']
#if possible duplicates remove them
#s = df1.melt().drop_duplicates('value').set_index('value')['variable']

df2['ID_name'] = df2['ID'].map(s)
print (df2)
   ID ID_name
0  a1      1A
1  b1      1B
2  c4      1C
3  c3     NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df1.melt())
  variable value
0       1A    a1
1       1A    a2
2       1A    a3
3       1B    b1
4       1B    b2
5       1B    b3
6       1C    c1
7       1C    c2
8       1C    c4
```

Comment: whats the values and variable here?